# Multiply feature map by a scalar in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I have a binary classification problem, there are image and variable in the data set, I have an idea for compare image and variable together.

Every time when I pass conv-layer, I want to multiply a weight scalar to all feature map, where weight scalar is computed from a fc-layer.

For example, suppose batch size is 8, there are two tensor `x1` and `x2`, where `x1`’s size is (8,3,224,224) and `x2`’s size is (8,16).

```
import torch 
from torch.nn import Module, Sequential
from torch.nn import Conv2d, BatchNorm2d, ReLU, MaxPool2d, Softmax, Linear
import numpy
batch_size = 8
x1 = torch.rand(batch_size*3*224*224).view(batch_size,3,224,224)
x2 = torch.rand(batch_size*16).view(batch_size,16)
```

I define conv-layer and fc-layer and compute the output from image and variable.

```
conv_01 = Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels= 9, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
linear_02 = Linear(16, 1)
c1 = conv_01(x1) ## torch.Size([8, 9, 224, 224])
c2 = linear_02(x2) ## torch.Size([8, 1])
```

The problem is to write the suitable code as below.

```
## I want to do like blow
## c1[0,:,:,:] = c1[0,:,:,:] * c2[0,0] # 1st data in the mini-batch
## c1[1,:,:,:] = c1[1,:,:,:] * c2[0,1] # 2nd data in the mini-batch
## c1[2,:,:,:] = c1[2,:,:,:] * c2[0,2]
## c1[3,:,:,:] = c1[3,:,:,:] * c2[0,3]
## c1[4,:,:,:] = c1[4,:,:,:] * c2[0,4]
## c1[5,:,:,:] = c1[5,:,:,:] * c2[0,5]
## c1[6,:,:,:] = c1[6,:,:,:] * c2[0,6]
## c1[7,:,:,:] = c1[7,:,:,:] * c2[0,7]
## output is a (8, 9, 224, 224)
## and do more layer like this operation
```

I already took a look in the [Multiply feature map by a learnable scalar](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/multiply-feature-map-by-a-learnable-scalar/1520).
But this only support when batch size is 1, but in my case, batch size is more than 1.
How to write a suitable code to the **forward** function in my case?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```py
result = c1 * c2.reshape((-1,1,1,1))
```

You can reshape your `c2` shape `torch.Size([8, 1])` to `torch.Size([8, 1, 1, 1])` using [`torch.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.reshape) so you can do multiplication with `c1` shape `torch.Size([8, 9, 224, 224])`